# Python: Wait for process to finish before proceeding in loop?

Tags: python, pdfkit

I'm attempting to use PDFkit to create PDFs of a site and I'm having some trouble:

```
for u in urls:
    for c in u.children:
        pdfkit.from_url(c, "test.pdf", configuration=config)
```

Running `pdfkit` on a single URL works fine, but trying to use it in a `for` loop causes problems. I think it's because it takes a while for each PDF to be generated.

Is there a way I could wait while `pdfkit` is running, and only proceed with the next URL when it has finished with the previous?

Comment: You could change the file for each location? or are you trying to put all locations into one pdf?

Comment: @busfault I changed it to allow for a new file name each time, but still get an error. It starts processing the first page of the first URL, then:  Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError

Comment: What is the actual error message? As you said, it might be related to something going on after the function call returns. Have you tried using distinct  file names? E.g. `for i, u in enumerate(urls): ...  from_url(c, "test_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".pdf", ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need async/wait function for python.

so, look at these

http://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html